# How to reinstall .NET Framework 4/4.6 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-framework, debug

If .NET Framework is broken or anything they let you download their installer (offline/web) but it doesn't work, you just bounce back a message that current or later version is already installed and it stops you from reinstalling.

I need this to fix broken fonts issue after latest Creators update.

Reference to my previous question: [PowerShell font Terminal is broken after Windows 10 Creators update](https://superuser.com/questions/1199605/powershell-is-broken-after-windows-10-creators-update)

And read one of the answers:

```
It happened before. An update affected a MOF file in the build package, the update breaking PowerShell DSC.

The ASCII chars are proof of DSC corruption.

Uninstall and reinstall .net Framework. Also, The .NET framework repair tool may fix the issue. you can get ithere
```

That repair tool legit does nothing and it also tells you to reinstall net framework, but its not even possible to do it on Windows 10.

Also there is no .NET framework under installed programs or updates or anywhere to uninstall it.

Running the .NET Cleaning Utility and unticking .NET Framework 3.5 and 4 under Programs and Features still blocks from installing from offline/web installer:
[image]

By nothing I mean at the end of the day I fail to run the web or offline installer of net framework 4/4.5/4.6

**UPDATE:** Irrelevant now, latest updates fixed the fonts error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET framework is a Windows Feature (as of Windows 8 or even as far back as 7) found under "Programs and Features".  I have had some good success with the following procedure:

1. Disabling the feature (.NET 4 and 3.5).
2. Reboot the computer.
3. Manually force a WindowsUpdate check to make sure everything is on the latest version.
4. Re-enable the feature(s) and then run WindowsUpdate again.

Last resort measure: Install one of the Visual Studio development environments (Express edition is good enough.) This also forces a refresh of .NET.

If that doesn't fix the problems nothing else will.
Because it is an integrated feature of Windows a really broken .NET environment is basically a broken Windows installation needing a re-install of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 Creators update includes the .net framework 4.7, so you can't reinstall it.

The software you try to install doesn't know that fact and checks the entry `Version` under the keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
```

for .net 4.6.

And in Creators update the version is `4.7.02046`, which the tools don't support.

So fake the .net version and change the Version entry to `4.6.01586`, install the tool and after setup, change the version back to `4.7.02046`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Programs and Features, click on everything that starts with "Microsoft .NET," (newest versions first) and Uninstall.

Remove traces of it by using  .NET Framework Setup Cleanup Utility .

Reinstall it from off-line installer or use `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`  to re-update it.

Try installing [this official version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344).

Comment: Like I mentioned there is not a single entry of .NET on uninstall program list. Also like I mentioned Cleanup Utility does nothing. DISM doesn't do nothing either. My question is what is the purpose of the installers then if they report there's already installed version and they won't install/reinstall after running all of these procedures.

Comment: Did you use this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/ ?

Comment: Try installing the one I linked in the answer.

Comment: You can also manually remove it's files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET (v 4.0 folder).

Comment: I updated my question post with screenshot and a description. This is what I get with the installer. I did delete the dir before together with /assembly/ dir and ended up reinstalling Windows to recover from it, because that broke everything, e.g. MMC wouldn't run, Event Viewer etc. And installer still wouldn't install.

Comment: You should not touch assembly, only the .exes and configs from sub-folder 4.0 would suffice for a repair.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.0 can't be reinstalled on Windows 10 because it's integrated into the OS. For me issues were detected by the [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/archive/blogs/astebner/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide) (hint: the *View Log* button opens the full log, but there's a log with just errors in the same directory) but .NET Framework Repair Tool couldn't fix the problem.

A Windows 10 upgrade solved the issue, though. I've upgraded from version 2004 to 20H2 and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score -3):

You can download Windows 10 ISO of the build you want, or have the new one.

Get a tool called NTlite. You don't need the license for this tool.

Copy all files to C:\folder from mounted Windows 10 ISO.

Now use NTlite to remove specific only Net Framework 4+ in components.
To be able to do that use the compatible settings to turn of the locked system.

Now just start a setup in the folder of edited Windows. And keep settings and apps for just a fresh install of Windows system files. It will also keep your windows activated without need for reactivation.

That way you are able to install Net Framework 4.5+. But unable for 4.0.

Comment: I have my doubts this method works for Windows 8+