# How to do a clean re-install of .NET in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

This OEM tool that I use a lot started crashing in one particular feature. Below is part of the error log. Adlib Designer is the tool, the Adapl parser is the feature, a simple embedded code editor with syntax hightlighting and a few basic options for compiling. On the failing system, syntax highlighting does not work and the feature crashes the whole tool a few seconds after being launched.

```
Application: ADLIBDesigner.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: the process ended due to an unhandled exception.
Exception information: System.ArgumentException
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
   at Adlib.Designer.ApplicationBrowser.PropertyPages.AdaplProperties.AdaplParser_ParseComplete(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at Adlib.Designer.AdlibDesignerMain.AdaplParser.Parse()
```

.NET Frameworks 3.5 and 4.8 are installed on my pc. OS is Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.18363.592. Latest installed updates are:

```
2020-01 Cumulative update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 Windows 10 version 1909 for x64 KB4534132 and KB4532938 
2019-12 Cumulative update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 Windows 10 version 1909 for x64 KB4533002
```

I ran Microsoft's [.NET repair tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135), but it did not solve the problem.

I'm suspecting a corruption in some .NET module because

1. the exact same tool works fine on an other (much older & slower) pc, with the same Windows version and the same updates.
2. the crash happens in `System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke`, ie not in an OEM-module.

I reported the problem to the maker of the tool. They can't reproduce the problem either, so a solution from them is not to be expected.

I'm thinking of doing a clean re-install of .NET. Does that make sense? If so, how can I do that?

The only other option I can think of: re-install Windows. I'd rather not go that path, because I'd have to reload my workhorse pc with everything it needs to work comfortably.

Comment: Open Control Panel, Programs and Features, Uncheck both .NET apps. Close, restart the computer, go back CHECK both .NET apps. Close, restart again and test your application.

Comment: Before you spend to much time trying to reinstall .NET Framework 4.8, which can't actually be reinstalled, verify the program works on a Windows 10 version 1909 VM.  I had a similar issue a few months ago, the problem was solved, by performing an upgrade to 1909.  All similar problems all suggested a in-place upgrade would work, I wasn't willing to do that, was simply lucky the upgrade to 1909 worked.  **However, in my case, the program didn't even launch.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall .NET Framework 4/4.6 on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1201498/how-to-reinstall-net-framework-4-4-6-on-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1502779/completely-missing-dot-net-in-windows-10-1909?rq=1

Comment: @John Wouldn't have thought it'd be that simple, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: @Ramhound Many thanks for all your suggestions. Unfortunately, I think I'm reaching the point where Windows re-install takes less time than trying out all the other things. A VM would fix, it works on a different real one. I also installed Visual Studio hoping it would force a .NET re-install, but the problem remains.

Comment: It seems that is what you must do now.